# Play framework: How do I print index number inside scala template by using map

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Hi I am pretty new in play framework and scala, continue I am reading the play documentation but I am facing problem while printing the index inside the map in the scala template file. I have tried below code but it was not working for me.

//Attempt 1: But not working

```
@(customer: Customer, orders: Seq[Order])
<h1>Welcome @customer.name!</h1>

<ul> 
@orders.map { case(index,order) =>
  <li>@index</li>
  <li>@order.title</li>
} 
</ul>
```

//Attempt 2: But not working

```
@(customer: Customer, orders: Seq[Order])
<h1>Welcome @customer.name!</h1>

<ul> 
@orders.map { order =>
  <li>@order.index</li>
  <li>@order.title</li>
} 
</ul>
```

Please give me some solution for this or give something other reference/resource link for play where I can explore more. You can find the above example from [play documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaTemplates).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `zipWithIndex`. It takes a list and creates a tuple from it where the first part is the element of the list and second is the index.

Example:

```
@orders.zipWithIndex.map { case (order, index) =>
  <li>@index</li>
  <li>@order.title</li>
}
```

Comment: it shows on the top `compile error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 1`

Comment: actually what type of value has your `zipWithIndex` object? It has separate object named `index` like `title` ???

Comment: [`zipWithIndex`](http://daily-scala.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/zipwithindex.html) takes a list and pairs it with and index. Meaning if you have a `Seq[Order]` then you will get a `Seq[(Order, Int)]` and then we do a `case` extractor on this to split them up: `case (order, index) =>`.
Your error message seems to be something else. Are you calling your view correctly? I will be able to try this out when I get home.

Comment: Oh its working fine now... thanks... actually I didn't know about the `zipWithIndex` so I was manually creating it that's why it was not working.

Comment: Yes, that's a Scala built-in collection function.